# Show it is a field

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose that $\Omega \in \mathcal{F}$ and that $A,B \in \mathcal{F}$ implies $A-B = A\cap B^c \in \mathcal{F}$ .

Show that $\mathcal{F}$ is field

My solution:

i)  $\Omega \in \mathcal{F}$

ii) $B \in  \mathcal{F}$   ,  $A \cap B^c \in \mathcal{F}$ , because {$A \cap B^c  \subset  B^c  $ } Thus  $B^c \in \mathcal{F}$

iii) IF $A,B  \in \mathcal{F} $, from assumption, implies  $A \cap B^c \in \mathcal{F}$  , I am not sure how to show $A  U B \in \mathcal{F}$

I also think I have done an error in ii)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your explanation for part $2$ is unclear. But it is easy, just note that $B^c=\Omega\cap B^c$.

As for part $3$, let $A,B\in\mathcal{F}$. By part $2$ we know that $A^c,B^c\in\mathcal{F}$ as well. Then $A^c\cap B^c\in\mathcal{F}$ (because $A^c,B\in\mathcal{F}$), and again by part $2$ $A\cup B=(A^c\cap B^c)^c\in\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: @GAGA No, I mean exactly $A^c,B\in\mathcal{F}$. Then by what is given we conclude that $A^c\setminus B=A^c\cap B^c\in\mathcal{F}$ as well.

Answer (score 1):

For ii) just write $B^{c}$ as $\Omega \setminus B$.  So $B^{c} \in \mathcal A$ for all $B \in \mathcal A$

For iii) note that $A\cap B =A\setminus B^{c} \in \mathcal A$ (where we have used ii). Now $(A\cup B)^{c}=(A^{c}\cap B^{c}) \in \mathcal A$ so $ A\cup B \in \mathcal A$.